# cubic spline in python

Tags: python, spline

i need to make a code for a cubic spline splot in python. I have 19 data points $(x_i,f_i)$ and could implementa code to solve the coefficients. In the last step i defined the spline function by using the data points and the solved coefficients.

```
x_val = np.linspace(-9, 9, 10)

def spline(t):
    for i in range(1,19):
        if x[i-1]<=t<=x[i]:
            s=f[i-1]+d[i-1]*(t-x[i-1])+1/2*g_1[i-1]*(t-x[i-1])**2+1/6*((g_1[i]-g_1[i-1])/h)*(t-x[i-1])**3
            return s
        
plt.plot(x_val,spline(x_val))
plt.show()
```

If i try some inputs i get the right output. For example: one data point is $(x_{10},f_{10})=(0,5)$. If i try "spline(0)" i'll get "spline(0)=5.0000000001". But if i try to plot the function, i get the message:

"if x[i-1]<=t<=x[i]:
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()"

Can anybody help me to solve this problem. I'm a totally Newbie in programming with python :(

I tried using

```
from array import *
```

but i have absolutely no idea how to use it

Comment: What's the value of `x` in this code?

Comment: Do you have to implement it yourself? I’m pretty sure scipy has a module that does cubic splines